# more adjectives or characteristics of something with hyphens

Tags: adjectives, hyphens

I want to know if there's a rule that I could use to form words with hyphens, which generally give a characteristic for something.
Ex:

a know-it-all person.
a story-driven videogame.
a two-faced person.

these are the ones I ever heard, but can i improvise and say something like: three-sided highway?

Comment: They are called compound adjectives. You can search using that phrase and find sites like [this one](https://7esl.com/compound-adjectives/)

Comment: Just because you can string words together doesn't mean they make sense. I can't imagine what a three-sided highway might mean. A ***two-sided highway*** isn't a valid collocation anyway, but at least I could guess it means what we in the UK call a "dual carriageway" (a road with with a dividing strip between the traffic in opposite directions and usually two or more lanes in each direction). But what would the 3rd element be in a "**triple** carriageway"? An overhead monorail above the road? A tunnel *under* it?

Comment: @FumbleFingers - (UK) when I was a boy, and my family got its first car, my father was worried about 'three-lane roads' which had a bad reputation for accidents. The idea was that the middle lane could be used for overtaking by cars going in either direction (!). The middle lane was often called the 'suicide lane' or 'chicken lane'. They were a relic of earlier times when traffic was much lighter, and trucks were much slower. They were mostly phased out by the end of the 1960s, but some [still survive](https://www.sabre-roads.org.uk/wiki/index.php?title=S3).

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: Indeed. I may be mistaken, but I think that back in the late 60s / early 70s when I started driving, Sussex (*my* stomping ground) was *particularly* notorious for having so many of those  dangerously-shared middle lanes. Over the next decade or so they all seemed to disappear (the road was widened, or the middle lane was *exclusively* given over to one direction). But around 2000, when some of my family moved to North Lincolnshire, I was more than a bit surprised to discover a very dangerous section like that just south of Louth. Lincs traffic accident rates are *appalling*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - the A20 near Brands Hatch was notorious; people called it 'Death Hill', there were stretches in Surrey near Guildford, and I remember the A38 near Bristol Airport which the Bristol Evening Post called 'Bristol's Death Highway'. This was the early 1970s. The technical term used by road folk is 'S3'.

Comment: There has been a general tendency in English to mash together words, first with hyphen, and then into a compound word, as in https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=bath+tub%2C+bathtub&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3  However, see https://www.editorgroup.com/blog/to-hyphenate-or-not-to-hyphenate/ for guidance.

Comment: The part of a highway used by cars travelling in one direction is usually called a 'lane' in careful speech or writing, although informally we may say that on a two-lane road the cars coming in the opposite direction are 'on the other side'.